# How to publish my open source library to Maven?

Tags: distribution, java, maven

I wrote a GNU-GPLv3 [Java library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)).
I want to make it available to people who use a [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) build script (pom.xml)

- How to do?
- What are the pre-requisites?

Comment: How is this related to open source at all? Is this about how you publish on Maven central?

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne: Maven is the main way to distribute open source JARs. Nearly all open source libraries can be found on Maven. Yet there are so many sites like mvnrepository.com or central.sonatype.org it is hard to figure out what open source project managers are supposed to do. This question is very much about open source, because a proprietary publisher would use Maven totally differently.

Comment: fair enough, but this question seems overly broad to elicit any answer. What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I suspect an answer would be something like "*The place to upload your JAR is <some URL>, other websites just mirror JARs from there. Just create an account and use this mvn command: <some mvn command line>". Beforehand, make sure your JAR does not include any class from other libraries already present on Maven, which you can check at that URL (I totally made up this rule), and modify your POM this way and that way, and remove "-SNAPSHOT" for the version name, and <a few other rules that are not obvious to guess>.*".

Comment: I expect readers of this QA to be already familiar with Maven as a user, but not as a publisher.

Comment: May be you could rephrase the question about how to publish an open source, Java-based project on Maven? Do you intend to provide some answer too?

Comment: note that readers may not be familiar at all with Maven unless you assume that everyone here is a developer and a Java developer

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne: I rephrased, is it better? (I hope that phrasing will not get me downvotes from people saying "*Maven is not only a repository, it is also a tool*") Thanks for your feedback! I intend to provide an answer once I have figured out the solution. Not that easy: Maven.org redirects to search.maven.org which does not seem to have any upload option.

Comment: this looks OK I guess: the question title makes sense

Comment: I'm really not sure this is on-topic here. I can't actually make the call either way, but to me, this is a technical question and should be on SO rather than here (where it would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846802/how-to-manually-publish-jar-to-maven-central).

Comment: @ArtOfCode: StackOverflow likes questions containing source code, so I am afraid that question might be closed in the future if SO becomes a bit stricter. By the way, it recommends using sonatype-oss, which actually is deprecated.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul This is on topic for SO - sure, they *like* code, but questions about tools are also on topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way is to use sonatypes procedure: http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html

It is basically 2 steps:

1. setup an account with them (free, but you need to tell them about a page you own or belong to)
2. setup some basic things in your pom or its parent.

For my projects I create a parent-pom in https://github.com/openCage/pfabulist-parent. branch v1.

Use it just copy stuff in your pom.

Then a maven deploy will send your artifact to sonatype.
They test some points and then send it to maven-central.

P.S.

By the way, to check whether your GPL3 license fits to the dependencies you are using there are several options.

- Philippe Ombredanne tool: https://github.com/nexB
- mine as java dependency: https://github.com/openCage/loracle-maven-plugin

Comment: thanks for the nice word! I always toyed with the idea of bundling scancode as a Jar btw... Most of it should be runnable on Jython...